# I can I integrate Apache and Mysql in the application installer?

Tags: java, mysql, apache, installation, advanced-installer

I have an Application made with java ,and it needs a Mysql database ,and Apache server,and I use Advanced Insaller to generate the installer.

I want the installer to install Mysql and Apache ,and Run them (I think as a service )so the user doesn't have to worry about it.

Can I do this with Advanced Installer?

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is [adding them as prerequisites](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html#prerequisites).

It's pretty straightforward. The hardest part is to determine a detection criteria for each prerequisite (a file or registry entry installed by it). But you can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) for this (see what the prerequisite installs).